# Fatal error: Call to undefined function : WP functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I'm new in wordpress and I'm creating my resume with it, I converted a page HTML5 to wordpress and now i want to add widgets to my template, I want to add a contact form. I enqueued the CSS and the Scripts and now I added a new function to create a new widget like that:

[image]

I refreshed the dashboard of wordpress to check if my widget has been added or not, so i got this error :

[image]

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Your scope is incorrect for starters - contact_sidebar() is only accessible inside create_sidebars()

Comment: no, it does not exist !!

Comment: I just took a closer look - contact_sidebar() isn't set properly - it's an array. You should write is as $contact_sidebar = array(   ....    );

Comment: But I got the function from the wp documentation, it's like that !!

Comment: That's not valid PHP in your code - sorry, it's just not

Comment: I modified the function as $contact_sidebar = array( .... ); so i didn't get the "Widgets" into "Appearance" !!

Comment: But no parse error now right? Try as the last line of the function: return $contact_sidebar;

Answer (score 0):

The noun of the array must be register_sidebar otherwise it will not work

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeuik.png)